# .mapでbreak処理をするにはどうしたらよいか

Tags: swift

Swiftの通常のfor文で、以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
import Foundation

let testArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
var newArray = [Int]()
for test in testArray
{
    newArray.append(test*2)
    if test == 4
    {
        break
    }
}
print(newArray)
```

このコードを実行すると、`[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`がprintされます。

しかし、for文より.mapのほうが処理速度が早いという記事を読んだので
これを.mapに書き換えたいと考えています。
ただ、.mapだとbreak文に相当するものがあるのか分かりません。

以下のようなコードを書いたのですが、breakするにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
また、.mapの使用方法にもやや自信がないのですが、このような場合、filterなどを使ったほうが良いのでしょうか？

```
import Foundation

let testArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
var newArray = [Int]()
_ = testArray.map
{
    let test = $0
    newArray.append(test*2)
    if test == 4
    {
        //break
    }
}
print(newArray)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for文より.mapのほうが処理速度が早いという記事を読んだ

場合によりけりです。for-inを使ったコードを`map`に置き換えれば必ず早くなるとは思わない方がいいでしょう。

> 以下のようなコードを書いたのですが、breakするにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
> また、.mapの使用方法にもやや自信がないのですが、このような場合、filterなどを使ったほうが良いのでしょうか？

Swiftの`map`には途中でのbreakを実現する機能はありません。

たとえば出来るだけ`map`の働きを生かして書こうと思うと、こんな感じになるでしょう。

```
    let endIndex = testArray.firstIndex(of: stopValue) ?? testArray.endIndex
    let newArray = testArray[0...endIndex]
        .map {$0 * 2}
```

(`stopValue`には、あなたのコードで`4`に相当する値が入っている想定。)

但し、最初に書きましたが、手元でmacOSのCommand Line Toolプロジェクトとして配列の要素数を1億(停止する要素の位置を4千万番目)とかでRelease設定(最適化が`-O`:速度優先になる)で実行時間を比べてみましたが、どちらかが有意に高速と言う結果は得られませんでした。

```
import Foundation

let testArray = Array(0..<100_000_000)
let stopValue = 40_000_000

do {
    let start = Date()
    let endIndex = testArray.firstIndex(of: stopValue) ?? testArray.endIndex
    let newArray = testArray[0...endIndex]
        .map {$0 * 2}
    let end = Date()
    print(newArray.count, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
    print(newArray.reduce(0, +))
}

do {
    let start = Date()
    var newArray = [Int]()
    //newArray.reserveCapacity(testArray.count)
    for test in testArray
    {
        newArray.append(test*2)
        if test == stopValue
        {
            break
        }
    }
    let end = Date()
    print(newArray.count, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
    print(newArray.reduce(0, +))
}
```

私の手元での実行結果

```
40000001 0.18691504001617432
1600000040000000
40000001 0.2031090259552002
1600000040000000
```

---

「for文より.mapのほうが処理速度が早い」といった単純化されすぎてときに適切ではなくなる「標語」を覚えるのではなく、配列に要素を追加していく処理を繰り返す場合、最初に`reserveCapacity`を呼んでおくと高速化できる、と言った要素を個別に覚えていかれた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。reserveCapacityを知らなかったので調べてみます！

Answer (score 1):

Sequence.map の実装は以下にあります。

[swift/Sequence.swift at main · apple/swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L622)

これを元に `mapUntil` メソッドを作成するという方法も考えられます。判定用の `condFunc`(closure) を追加しています。

```swift
extension Sequence {
  public func mapUntil<T>(
    _ transform: (Element) throws -> T,
    until condFunc: (Element) -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> [T] {
    let initialCapacity = underestimatedCount
    var result = ContiguousArray<T>()
    result.reserveCapacity(initialCapacity)

    var iterator = self.makeIterator()

    // Add elements up to the initial capacity without checking for regrowth.
    for _ in 0..<initialCapacity {
      let element = iterator.next()!
      result.append(try transform(element))
      if condFunc(element) {
        return Array(result)
      }
    }
    // Add remaining elements, if any.
    while let element = iterator.next() {
      result.append(try transform(element))
      if condFunc(element) {
        break
      }
    }
    return Array(result)
  }
}
```

**動作確認**

```
let testArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print("testArray:", testArray)
for i in [4, 2, 0, 6] {
  print(
    String(format: "%d:", i),
    testArray.mapUntil({ $0 * 2 }, until: { $0 == i })
  )
}

=>
testArray: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
4: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
2: [0, 2, 4]
0: [0]
6: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```